# Entropy of $f(x)=1$

Tags: integration, logarithms, information-theory, entropy

Let $f(x)$ be a *probability density function* $f(x) = 1$ on $x = [0,1]$, and entropy defined as
$$H(p(x)) = -\int p(x) \log_2(p(x)) \, dx$$ where $p(x)$ is a *pdf*. Unless I've made an arithmetic error, the entropy of $H(f(x)) = 0$. $$H(f(x)) = -\int_0^1 1\log_2(1) \,dx = 0$$ Given that other uniform distributions maximize entropy, this seems counter-intuitive. Other than mathematical definitions, is there an intuitive explanation why this is true? (Assuming it is true.)

Comment: Probability mass functions are normally associated with discrete distributions, the continuous analogue is a probability density function. Try looking at a more generic (continuous) uniform distribution on $[a, b]$ and you will find that the entropy is equal to $\ln(b - a)$, which fits with your result

Comment: Your intuition (I assume) comes from [discrete entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_%28information_theory%29#Definition). The function $H$ is the [differential entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_entropy) which does not share all properties of discrete entropy (such as uniform distributions $\implies$ maximize entropy) and can give such counter-intuitive results.

Comment: You're completely correct about probability mass functions, I edited to reflect that. Also pointing out the differences between discrete entropy and differential entropy is useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Differential Entropy can actually be negative, which is one of it's drawbacks. It just so happens that on $[0,1]$ all continuous distribution entropies are negative except for the uniform distribution. Let $h(x)$ be any continuous distribution on $[0,1]$ and $u(x)=1$ be the uniform distribution. Here's the proof using KL divergence notation::

$$0\leq D_{KL}(h(x))||u(x))=\int_0^1 h(x) \log( h(x)/u(x))dx=-H(h(x))-\int_0^1 h(x)\log(u(x))dx=-H(h(x)),$$

since $u(x)=1$. So

$$H(h(x))\leq 0.$$

By the way, positivity of KL divergence is a consequence of Jenson's inequality:

$$D_{KL}(f||g)=\int\log \left(\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\right)[f(x)dx]=\int-\log(g(x)/f(x)) [f(x)dx]\geq -\log(\int g(x)dx)=0$$